# Not looking for VS2013 npm install node modules

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, npm-install

I have a problem when ran command "npm install". I want install gulp and bower modules, but when i ran "npm install" or "npm install bower" I got an error VS2013. Why I got this error? How to solve this problem? below specified version I installed:

node v10.15
npm v6.10.3
python v2.7
VSCODE v1.37.1 (user setup)

I already add proxy on config:
+ npm config set https-proxy http://xxxxx
+ npm config set proxy http://xxxxx
+ npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
+ npm config set ca ""
+ npm config set strict-ssl false

Below this error log:

> gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
>   gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
>   gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer
>   gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
>   gyp ERR! find VS - not found
>   gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
>   gyp ERR! find VS
>   gyp ERR! find VS 
>   gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
>   gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
>   gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
>   gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
>   gyp ERR! find VS 
>   gyp ERR! find VS
>   gyp ERR! configure error
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
>   gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\c93134\AppData\Roaming\n
>   pm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)

Answer (score 5):

For that to work you must install Visual Studio Tools (2015 version worked for me).
You can find them on Microsoft site.

[go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Link takes to Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 - Microsoft https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126